# Should Selenium Questions be in a separate site?

Tags: discussion

Since many (if not most) questions lately are Selenium-specific, should a new Selenium Stack Exchange be created, leaving more general SQA questions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is no. The [Selenium proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium) was merged into the [SQA proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2241/software-quality-assurance-testing) which is what pushed SQA over the top and into beta. Seeing as how the stats for SQA barely stand up for itself currently, I imagine it being split would make two very nonviable sites.

Only problem is it appears the documentation on the merger has been deleted, and I can't even find it on the Way Back Machine.

Comment: Makes sense to me. I hadn't realized Selenium was intentionally merged into SQA. Unfortunate, but oh well.

Comment: Maybe the non-Selenium people (like me) need to be asking more questions

Comment: @Joe I wish there was enough interest in the Stack Exchange community to support both. Personally, I would prefer more questions on the "science and art" of SQA as opposed to the vocational knowledge of the tools themselves. As it stands, we're treading water with it merged.

Comment: I like both types of questions and I feel like so long as we have the expertise and it's not completely disruptive it is good to have them together in one place.  Making sure questions are tagged and titled well enough to be relevant is pretty important though.

Answer (score 0):

At that rate have it be selenium and junit. 90% of the questions here, really. I don't see SQA standing on its own though.